# is there a typescript utility to extract a child type from parent type?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Human {
    name: string;
    address: {
        city: string;
    }
}

const h: Human = {
    name: "abc",
    address: {
        city: 'SF'
    }
};

function printAddress(address) { }   

printAddress(h.address);
```

In function `printAddress(address) { }`, I want to say that address argument is of type `Human.address`. Instead of declaring a new type `Address`, is there any TS utility type to achieve this?

`Pick<Human, ‘address’>` did not work. because Pick creates a wrapper type for `address`

Comment: `type Address = Human["address"]`

Comment: I can declare a new type `Address`. But I am looking for some utility that identifies the type without needing to declare a new type. something like Pick

Comment: You may not declare it as a separate type. Just use it inline `function printAddress(address: Human["address"])`

Comment: Just use it inline, you don't have to declare it manually.